# Android camera preview: 1:1 aspect ratio, how?

Tags: android

Hi
I am trying to use the camera to capture an image in one of my application. What is special is that I need a square preview area (and picture in the end). I tried defining the size of both picture and preview to 1:1 pixel ratios, but nothing seams to work. No matter what I does the picture looks "squashed" on a square.

Anyone who has any idea about how to resolve this?

code:

```
public class AddFromCameraActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private Camera mCamera;
private Parameters mParameters; 
private SurfaceView mCameraPreview;
private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addimagefromcameramain); 
    initialise(); 
    //Testing area
    mCamera = Camera.open(); 
    mParameters = mCamera.getParameters(); 
    mParameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO); 
    mParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO); 
    mParameters.setJpegQuality(50); 
    mParameters.setJpegThumbnailQuality(50); 
    mParameters.setPictureSize(1024, 1024);
    //mParameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG); 
    mParameters.setJpegThumbnailSize(256, 256); 
    mParameters.setPreviewSize(500, 500); 
    mCamera.setParameters(mParameters);
}
private void initialise()
{
    mCameraPreview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.cameraSurfaceView); 
    mSurfaceHolder = mCameraPreview.getHolder(); 
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this); 
    mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); 
    mSurfaceHolder.setFixedSize(500, 500); 
}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {

}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mCamera.stopPreview(); 
    mCamera.release(); 
}
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    mCamera.release(); 
}
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look at the [CameraPreview sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html) code from the Android SDK. The `getOptimalPreviewSize` method shows how to deal with different camera sizes and the `onLayout` method shows how to layout the preview surface in the activity.

Comment: Googled for CameraPreview implementations and found this. It seems to handle different aspect ratio. Gotta try it. https://github.com/pocorall/scaloid-apidemos/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.java